# Objective-CのopenURLで日本語URLが開けない

Tags: ios, objective-c

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@""]`
にて、日本語が含まれるURLが開けなくなったのですが、情報をお持ちの方はいらっしゃいますか？

コンソールには
`LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme (null)`
と表示されます。

開けないのは例えば以下のリンクになります。
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"http://お名前.com"];`
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"instagram://tag?name=焼肉"];`

それぞれSafariからは開けるので、実装上の不具合かなと思っています。
しかし、日本語の含まれないURLであれば上記のソースコードでURLを開くことはできます。
もともとは日本語を含むURLでも開けていたのですが、Xcode7にアップデートしたあたりから開けなくなったような気がしています。

何かできることがあれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ブラウザ等で日本語URLを入力した場合、内部的にはASCII文字列への変換が行われています。おそらく前者はPunycode、後者はパーセントエンコーディングという符号化を行う必要があるのでは。

Comment: Punycodeの符号化で`http://お名前.com`のリンクを開くことができました！ありがとうございます。
しかし、後者のパーセントエンコーディングを調べてやってみたのですが、うまくいかず。。念のためコード置いておきます

`NSString *encordedURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];`
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encordedURL]];`

Comment: その方法では"//"等もエスケープされてしまうように思います。"焼肉"だけをパーセントエンコードして"instagram://tag?name="と文字列結合してみては

Comment: @pgrho 焼肉だけをエンコードしたらできました！！ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 1):

ドメイン名に日本語が含まれる場合はPunycodeエンコーディングが必要です。
クエリに日本語が含まれる場合はパーセントエンコーディングが必要です。

共に対応しているライブラリがGitHubで公開されていました。
[Punycode-Cocoa](https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa)を使えば簡単に対応できます。

試しに使ってみたところ、

```
NSString *name = @"http://お名前.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:name.encodedURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

でSafariが起動して正しくページが表示されました。
URLが`https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=日本語`のパターンでも全く同じコードで問題なく開けました。
なので、`instagram://tag?name=焼肉`もこれでいけるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: `http://お名前.com`は正常に開けました！ありがとうございます！
`instagram://tag?name=焼肉`はInstagramのアプリは開けたのですが、`tag?name=焼肉`のところが正常に読み込まれなかったのか、ハッシュタグの画面一覧に遷移することができませんでした。
同様に自分が管理しているアプリでもURLSchemeからパラメータを取得するところで失敗していたので、同様の問題かなと。
もう少し調べてみます。